# JSPDF custom pdf name output()

Tags: php, pdf, output, jspdf

I'm trying to find a way to change the name, theoretically I send it, because if I use "save" if it downloads it with the name I sent it as a variable, but with bloburl, I don't know whether to modify the JS root of JSPDF, please help

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlRne.png)]

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc5ah.png)]

I would like a result like this, I saw it in a forum, but it did not say how it could be achieved
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fSf.png)]

I hope you can help me with this problem, I searched several forums and none found a solution

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)